# Error when trying to insert a new variable into a database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to insert a new varibale called `KEY_DAY` but whenever I try to insert it into the database, I get an error. Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public long createEntry(String name, String hotness) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
cv.put(KEY_HOTNESS, hotness);

     //here the value of person day is null coz ur not inserting anything use may be 
cv.put(KEY_DAY,""); or combine two functions to insert value together 
return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);


}

public long createEntry1(String day) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();//here the value is rest two fields is null
cv.put(KEY_DAY, day);


return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

}
```

Comment: i dont really understand are u telling me to add the extra values into the createEntry method?

Comment: see ur table has 3 fields but in one func ur inserting 2 values which means third one goes null and in other ur inserting 1 value means 2 goes null so try to insert all three values at once